# Mapbox markers - Changing colors dynamically based on frequent database updates or time intervals in JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mapbox

New to Mapbox and JS in general so pardon the ignorance. I have a map linked to a db that stores a lat/long and whether that point is reached. It displays all of the points on the map with its designated color (green if isPassed is True and blue if isPassed is False. I have a script running that periodically turns each point's isPassed value to True every few seconds and I'd like it reflect on the map whether that's on db update or a small set interval. Here's a snippet:

```
that.points.forEach(function (v) {
    var point = [v.Latitude, v.Longitude]
    var color;
            
    if(v.isPassed == 1){
        color = '#00FF00'
    } else{
        color = '#0000FF'
    }
    that.marker = L.circleMarker(point, {
        radius: 2,
        color: color,
    });
    that.marker.addTo(that.map);
});
```

I've tried refreshing the map itself with `window.reload()` but that behavior isn't very intuitive since it keeps flashing. Another idea was to see if I can place the markers onto a layer and reload the layer but the original mapboxjs documentation (not mapbox gl) doesn't have helpful examples so I'm lost. Any help is appreciated, thanks!